# How should I say correctly about using a tap or faucet

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request

How do we say when we try to use the tap in a kitchen or bathroom? Can I say "open the tap" or "turn on water"?

Answer (score 4):

You can say **turn on the tap** or **turn off the tap**.

In this meaning, the word tap is mostly used in the UK. On the other hand, in the US, the word faucet is chiefly used.

You can say **turn on the faucet** or **turn off the faucet**.

The difference between the words tap and faucet has been talked [here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68908/tap-faucet-spigot-what-are-the-differences)