# tap, faucet, tap water, faucet water

Tags: american-english, british-english

According to available information an element of a sink from which water flows is called A and the water from A is called B.

In BrE A=tap, B=tap water.

In AmE A=faucet, B=tap water.

Is that correct? An obvious question, can I say faucet water for the B in America?

Thank you.

Comment: Closely related: [Tap, faucet, spigot - what are the differences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68908/tap-faucet-spigot-what-are-the-differences)

Answer (score 2):

No, even though *faucet* is more common than *tap* or *spigot* for the thing that water comes out of, we say *tap water*, not *faucet water* or *spigot water*.

And we do know what a *tap* is — in fact, we call the thing on a keg of beer a *tap*, and a bartender would say they have Guinness *on tap*, and not *on faucet* or *on spigot*.

Comment: Whereas _faucet_ was unknown in the UK (as far as I know) until it started to be known from American films, and it is still hardly used.

Comment: But doesn't "tap water" come from a faucet? Isn't draught (draft) beer heard in the US?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, you can say *beer on tap* **or** *beer on draft*, and it is indeed called *draft beer* and not *tap beer*. We use *faucet*, *spigot*, or *tap*, although I think *Faucet* is most common. (maybe it depends on the region) for the thing in the kitchen.

Comment: Which begs the question why is it "tap water" in both the UK *and* the US but in the kitchen the fixtures on a sink have a different name depending which part of the world you live?